# DLL Injection With Windows 8.1 PE

Tags: win32gui

I tried Dll Injection on windows 8.1 P.E., works fine with explicitly      installed applications but it doesn't work with notepad, calc or internet explorer. My idea is that from windows xp onwards it is not supported like this way but didn't find any help over internet.

here's my code:

```
    #include <windows.h>  
    #include "resource.h"
    #include "..\HookInjEx_DLL\HookInjEx_DLL.h"

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // global variables & forward declarations
    //
    HWND hStart,hndl2,hndl3,hndl4,hndl5;        // handle to start buttoN 
    BOOL CALLBACK MainDlgProc (HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);


    //-----------------------------------------------
    // WinMain
    //
    int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                         HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                         LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                         int       nCmdShow)
    {

    // For Notepad --------------------------------------------------------------

        hStart = FindWindow(NULL,"Untitled - Notepad");
        hndl2 = FindWindowExA(hStart,NULL,"Edit",NULL);

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------



        ::DialogBoxParam (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE (IDD_WININFO), NULL, MainDlgProc, NULL);

        return 0;
    }


    //-----------------------------------------------
    // MainDlgProc
    // Notice: dialog procedure
    //
    BOOL CALLBACK MainDlgProc (HWND hDlg,   // handle to dialog box
                               UINT uMsg,      // message
                               WPARAM wParam,  // first message parameter
                               LPARAM lParam ) // second message parameter
    {
        static int bChecked = false;

        switch (uMsg) {

        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            ::SetTimer( hDlg, 101, 300, NULL );
            return true;

        // if running more instances of HookInjEx, 
        // keep their interface consistent
        case WM_TIMER:
            bChecked = (IsDlgButtonChecked( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON ) == BST_CHECKED);
            if( g_bSubclassed && !bChecked) {
                ::CheckDlgButton( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON, BST_CHECKED );
            //  ::SetDlgItemText( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON, "Unmap Dll" );
            }
            else if (!g_bSubclassed && bChecked) {
                ::CheckDlgButton( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON, BST_UNCHECKED );
                ::SetDlgItemText( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON, "Inject Dll" );
            }
            break;      

        case WM_COMMAND:
            if( !g_bSubclassed) {
                InjectDll( hndl2 );
            }
            else {
                if( !g_bSubclassed ) 
                    ::SetDlgItemText( hDlg, IDC_BUTTON, "Inject Dll" );
            }
            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            if( g_bSubclassed ) 

            ::EndDialog (hDlg, 0);
            break;      
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here's my code for DLL:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "HookInjEx_DLL.h"

//-------------------------------

#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Exdisp.h>

//This imports the shell extionsions
//we disable warnings of multiple defines
#pragma warning(disable: 4192)
#pragma warning(disable: 4146)
#import <mshtml.tlb>
#import <shdocvw.dll>

//-------------------------------

//-------------------------------------------------------------
// shared data 
// Notice:  seen by both: the instance of "HookInjEx.dll" mapped
//          into "explorer.exe" as well as by the instance
//          of "HookInjEx.dll" mapped into our "HookInjEx.exe"
#pragma data_seg (".shared")
int     g_bSubclassed = 0;  // START button subclassed?
UINT    WM_HOOKEX = 0;
HWND    g_hWnd  = 0;        // handle of START button
HHOOK   g_hHook = 0;
#pragma data_seg ()

#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.shared,RWS")


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// global variables (unshared!)
//
HINSTANCE   hDll;

// New & old window procedure of the subclassed START button
WNDPROC             OldProc = NULL; 
LRESULT CALLBACK    NewProc( HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM );

//--------------------------------------------------

// DllMain
//
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    if( ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH ) 
    {
        hDll = (HINSTANCE) hModule; 
        ::DisableThreadLibraryCalls( hDll );

        if( WM_HOOKEX==NULL )
            WM_HOOKEX = ::RegisterWindowMessage( "WM_HOOKEX_RK" );          
    }

    return TRUE;
}

#define pCW ((CWPSTRUCT*)lParam)

LRESULT HookProc (
  int code,       // hook code
  WPARAM wParam,  // virtual-key code
  LPARAM lParam   // keystroke-message information
)
{
    if( (pCW->message == WM_HOOKEX) && pCW->lParam ) 
    {
        ::UnhookWindowsHookEx( g_hHook );

        if( g_bSubclassed ) 
            goto END;       // already subclassed?

        // Let's increase the reference count of the DLL (via LoadLibrary),
        // so it's NOT unmapped once the hook is removed;
        char lib_name[MAX_PATH]; 
        ::GetModuleFileName( hDll, lib_name, MAX_PATH );

        if( !::LoadLibrary( lib_name ) )
            goto END;       

        // Subclass START button
        OldProc = (WNDPROC) 
            ::SetWindowLong( g_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)NewProc );
        if( OldProc==NULL )         // failed?
            ::FreeLibrary( hDll );
        else {                      // success -> leave "HookInjEx.dll"
            ::MessageBeep(MB_OK);   // mapped into "explorer.exe"
            g_bSubclassed = true;
        }       
    }
    else if( pCW->message == WM_HOOKEX ) 
    {
        ::UnhookWindowsHookEx( g_hHook );

        // Failed to restore old window procedure? => Don't unmap the
        // DLL either. Why? Because then "explorer.exe" would call our
        // "unmapped" NewProc and  crash!!
        if( !SetWindowLong( g_hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (long)OldProc ) )
            goto END;

        ::FreeLibrary( hDll );

        ::MessageBeep(MB_OK);
        g_bSubclassed = false;  
    }

END:
    return ::CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, code, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK NewProc(
  HWND hwnd,      // handle to window
  UINT uMsg,      // message identifier
  WPARAM wParam,  // first message parameter
  LPARAM lParam   // second message parameter
)
{
    switch (uMsg) 
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        MessageBox(NULL,"HI","",MB_OK);
                break;
    }

    return CallWindowProc( OldProc,hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam );
}

int InjectDll( HWND hWnd )
{   
    g_hWnd = hWnd;

    // Hook "explorer.exe"
    g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CALLWNDPROC,(HOOKPROC)HookProc,
                                hDll, GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd,NULL) );
    if( g_hHook==NULL )
        return 0;

    // By the time SendMessage returns, 
    // the START button has already been subclassed
    SendMessage( hWnd,WM_HOOKEX,0,1 );  
    return g_bSubclassed;
}
```

Comment: I've used `SetWindowsHookEx` with notepad.exe, etc... but not tried on Win8.  Are you compiling for X64?  You cannot inject a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process.  Also try your code on a Win7 machine to help simply the problem.

Comment: Hi,  Yes I am compiling for X64 but my dll is 64-bit. Now I am able to inject the dll but after injection my dll does nothing. Please help me out !!!!!

Comment: You can attach a debugger to the targeted process and debug your hook code.